# Python, program open and close in 10th of second

Tags: python, windows

Here is my code as follows.

```
# starting of Employee class
class Employee(object):
def __init__(self): #declaring Constructor
    self.name = ""
    self.iDnumber = ""
    self.department = ""
    self.jobTitle = ""

# setter methode for setting values to the class properties
def setName(self,name):
    self.name=name
def setIDnumber(self,iDnumber):
    self.iDnumber=iDnumber
def setDepartment(self,department):
    self.department=department
def setJobTitle(self,jobTitle):
    self.jobTitle=jobTitle

# getter methode for getting values of the class properties
def getName(self):
    return self.name
def getIDnumber(self):
    return self.iDnumber
def getDepartment(self):
    return self.department
def getJobTitle(self):
    return self.jobTitle

# methode which takes object as an argument and display its properties
def display(emp_object):
    print("Name : ",emp_object.getName())
    print("IDnumber : ",emp_object.getIDnumber())
    print("Department : ",emp_object.getDepartment())
    print("JobTitle : ",emp_object.getJobTitle())

# Main methode of the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    employeeList = [] #List to hold the Employee objects
        emp1 = Employee()
        emp2 = Employee()
        emp3 = Employee()

# appending objects to the list
        employeeList.append(emp1)
        employeeList.append(emp2)
        employeeList.append(emp3)

# Initializing each objects of the list
for employee in employeeList:
    emp_name = input("Enter your Name ")
        employee.setName(emp_name)
    emp_iDnumber = input("Enter your iDnumber ")
        employee.setIDnumber(emp_iDnumber)
    emp_department = input("Enter your Department ")
        employee.setDepartment(emp_department)
    emp_jobTitle = input("Enter your JobTitle ")
        employee.setJobTitle(emp_jobTitle)

# Displaying each objects of the list
for emp_object in employeeList:
    display(emp_object)
```

and, when I run it termianl just flash for a 10th of seconds and do not ask for input.

Help me with this thank you.

I am trying to focus on

Display a message asking user to enter employee name, ID, department, and title
b. Read employee name into a variable
c. Call the set name method of the first object passing the name
d. Read employee ID into a variable

Comment: Probably because some code is not properly indented?

Comment: You should indent your code

Comment: What is your coding environment? You can right click the executable file and unmark "Close on Exit", so that at least you can see what's happening on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are running it on windows... Simple add a input() at the end of you main to pause program and prevent windows from close it

And you need to indent your code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     employeeList = [] #List to hold the Employee objects
     emp1 = Employee()
     emp2 = Employee()
     emp3 = Employee()

# appending objects to the list
     employeeList.append(emp1)
     employeeList.append(emp2)
     employeeList.append(emp3)
     input()
```